# Модальное окно при клике ячейки таблицы

Tags: html

Как при клике на ячейку таблицы выползало модальное окно?

Comment: http://g.zeos.in/?q=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: дело в том , что на примерах показано открытие модального окна при нажатие на кнопку или же ссылку , а мне нужно при нажатие ячейки таблицы

Comment: @Давид Блаженство Используете `javascript` вместе с разметкой?

Comment: нет , желательно без него

Comment: без использования внутри td ссылки - на css это сделать не получиться

Comment: @Давид Блаженство Вам в любом случае надо отслеживать нажатие кнопки, чтобы выводить элементы в модальном окне.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Пример с использованием css

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal:target {
  display: flex;
}

.modal__content {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 25px;
}

.modal__close{
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#modal1">td1</a>
      <div class="modal" id="modal1">
        <div class="modal__content">
          modal 1
          <a href="#" class="modal__close">Close</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#modal2">td2</a>
      <div class="modal" id="modal2">
        <div class="modal__content">
          modal 2
          <a href="#" class="modal__close">Close</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```